# ActiveMQ Classic 5.18.3 running in a fail-over configuration using SQL Server as backend datastore throws Primary Key violation error

Tags: activemq-classic, failover

We have ActiveMQ Classic 5.18.3 running on two servers - S564 and S563. They are configured in a failover setup utilizing SQL Server as their back-end data store.

At random intervals, the following sequence of events occurs:

1. S564 logs `no longer able to keep the exclusive lock so giving up being a master`
2. S563 logs `S563, becoming master with lease expiry .....` and got exclusive lock for the database.
3. S564 logs `Waiting as there are still 2 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 293 seconds. Inflights per route: [route3 = 1, route2 = 1]`
4. S564 Keeps on logging `Waiting as there are still 2 inflight and pending exchanges to complete...` until the timeout is elapsed.
5. Server S563 logs:

   ```
   Ignoring SQLException, java.io.IOException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__ACTIVEMQ__3214EC27C'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ACTIVEMQ_MSGS'. The duplicate key value is (513793323).'
   ```

What is the reason for the SQL Server Primary Key Violation? How to resolve this?

Comment: An issue similar to this was recently raised on the [ActiveMQ users mailing list](https://lists.apache.org/thread/h1mqgmlm5thm463b5l945kt2sng6z6jm).

Comment: @Justin Bertram Thanks for the link. Unfortunately It does not seems to have any answer yet.

Comment: That's correct. There is no resolution to the problem yet, but someone may post an answer to the mailing list before you get an answer here. If there was already an answer on the mailing list I would have posted it as an answer here rather than simply providing a link in a comment.